# Do DynamoDB consumed capacity units in on-demand mode compare to provisioned capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Right now I am using on-demand mode for my DynamoDB tables, as I didn't know how much data to expect. But now that the application has run a while, I can see the metrics for ConsumedReadCapacityUnits and ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits for my tables in CloudWatch.

In on-demand mode I pay per request, whereas in provisioned capacity mode I have to pay for the provisioned capacity. If I simply take the metrics for (max) consumed capacity units and compare the prices of those in provisioned capacity mode to my current costs, I believe provisioned capacity mode would be a lot cheaper for me.

My question is, can I simply take the metrics and take the max (plus some buffer) of the consumed capacity units and configure them as provisioned capacity, or is that an error in reasoning on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two other things you need to consider:

1. How 'bursty' is your throughput?
2. Are you using SDKs to connect to your database?

Setting your provision to the maximum throughput you ever see will ensure you don't get throttled requests, however you will probably be setting the provision too high. Dynamodb can actually consume more provision than you have set using [Burst Capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting). This will accomodate short bursts of high throughput over the space of 5 minutes. If you see sustained peaks, for example your database is busy in the day but not the night, you might consider setting your tables to [Autoscale](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html). In this case you can set the provisioned throughput lower, and Dyanmodb will automatically scale up provision as required. Note that autoscale is good for workloads that vary over the course of hours (e.g. for handling daily peak hours). It's not good for reacting to events that occur in less than about 30 minutes.

If you are using official SDKs, they will handle throttle responses, and retry any failed requests. This gives Dynamodb some time to scale without your application failing requests.

Comment: Thank you. I do in fact have a very bursty setup, most of my data is read and written every 15 minutes with mostly idle phases in between, so Autoscale is probably not suitable. However, the required capacity seems to be so low, I believe even if I set the provisioned capacity higher that the current max, the cost should be almost neglectable (around 0,5% of the current costs, which made me wonder in the first place if I understood something wrong). Also I do use the SDK, so occasional throttling shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect you've got your numbers wrong. Provisioned capacity isn't that much cheaper, especially for small workloads. Do you want to ask them as a question and post the link here, I can take a look.

Comment: You're right, I've got my numbers wrong. The price for WCU/RCU are per hour, and I calculated per month. Sorry.